# Access div image in css

Tags: html, css

I want to setup a tiles view in HTML. Therefore I have deleted my previous list view with the following CSS Code

```
.tiles li * {
    display: none;
}

.tiles li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

In html my structure is looking like the short code below

```
<main class="tiles">
 <ul>
  <li class="grid-container">
   <div class="gridImageObject">
    <img src="./data/img/100_100.jpeg" class="align-left">
   </div>
  <another li image object...>
  </ul>
</main>
```

But in CSS I cannot access the image object. :( Only if I am going to delete the first div I can access it with

```
.tiles li img { display: inline-block; ..}
```

Is there a way to access the img element without deleting the first div element?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your issue is and what you're trying to do

Comment: Your code is essentially saying "don't display any items inside a `li` inside a `.tiles`". Your `div`, being a parent of the image, will hide itself and all its contents. So we might need more context on your code to understand what you are trying to hide exactly.

Comment: you have written "display: none".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your issue really is, for starters, you have the following rule:

```
.tiles li * {
    display: none;
}
```

Which is causing any element inside your `<li>` tags to NOT be displayed, so if you want to see any image, you need to remove that rule.

Then, you say you want to build a tiled layout, maybe CSS Grid would be a better option for you, pretty simple to do to create a, well, **grid** of items.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 115px);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 115px;
  width: 115px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Also, from what you posted after, I have to remind you that CSS' only job is to apply styles to the content you define in your HTML document, with CSS you are not "disabling" or "removing" the content of your HTML file, you are just hiding it... If you need a different element structure to apply different styles, you need to go to  your HTML file and make the changes there